# How to change chart background with MPAndroidChart library?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm using the amazing library [**MPAndroidChart**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). It works like a charm, except when I'm trying to change the background color of the BarData. Default color is white, and I want to change it to Transparent.

I've tried this :

```
Paint p1 = mChart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_GRID_BACKGROUND);
p1.setColor(Color.RED);
```

and this:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

... but it seems that doesnt works.

Any ideas ?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since [**release v1.6.5**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases), the background of the `Chart` is **transparent by default**. Meaning, that everything in the background (chart background, other `Views`, etc.) that is not overlayed by data drawn into the `Chart`, will be visible.

If you want to change the background (color, or maybe drawable), you can either do that by changing the chart-background

- in .xml (`android:background="..."`)
- by calling `setBackgroundColor(...)` or `setBackgroundResource(...)`

Another way could be to change the background of the parent layout that contains the `Chart`.

Comment: I'm just testing your new release, and the transparent background works like a charm ! Thanks again

Comment: @Philipp Can we set background only for ranges. As -30 and below red -10 below yellow and 10 above yellow and 30 above red

Answer (score 3):

Code to change Background color:

```
chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //set whatever color you prefer
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);// this is a must
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to Change Whole Screen Background Color

```
 Barchart chart;
 chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));//Set as a black
 chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);//set this to true to draw the grid background, false if not
```

Happy to help Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, after some research, I've found that it's not possible yet: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/53

Hope It will be possible soon ! =)