# MPAndroidChart - Set a background image

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I was trying to set a drawable as a background image to the LineChart.

```
chart.setBackground(drawable);
```

Also tried to set the image from resource as background.

```
chart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
```

None of the above seems working for MPAndroiChart, may be I'm missing to set any of the flags.

Though setting an image as a background to the graph doesn't seems logical but here in my case, I wish to customize the gird lines interval in the background. So, I'm planning to make it as a separate drawable layer and wish to place it behind the plot. Any inputs or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this answers from the author of the library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26220542/5352802     http://stackoverflow.com/a/27026727/5352802

Comment: Thanks buddy! I found the problem. Simply comment chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);